# Hydrogen fusion in the Sun-neutrino

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, sun, neutrinos, fusion

One of the ways nuclear fusion happens in the sun is deuterium and tritium fusion which forms a Helium-4 atom and a neutrino. What flavor of neutrino is created - a tau, muon, or electron neutrino?

Comment: D-T fusion produces a He4 plus a neutron. Not a neutrino. And I don't think D-T fusion is the primary fusion channel in the sun.

Comment: You are confused with proton-proton fusion http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/procyc.html which powers the sun and releases a  electron neutrino and a positron . As Jon said D-T releases a neutron  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html (second page)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting mixed up about the mechanism of fusion in the Sun. The first, and rate limiting, step is fusion of two protons to produce a deuteron, a positron and an electron neutrino. The neutrino is produced because the process is basically [beta plus decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission) to create a neutron then fusion of the neutron and a proton. That is the only step where a neutrino is produced.

From there fusion with another proton produces Helium-3 and the ${}^3$He nuclei react to produce ${}^4$He. This is described in detail in the [Wikipedia article on proton fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction).

The only place deuterium-tritium fusion is common is in hydrogen bombs and eventually (we hope) in fusion reactors. This reaction plays a negligible role in stellar fusion.